# Double clicking with CasperJS

Tags: javascript, casperjs, bots, double-click, steam

I am trying to make a bot with CasperJS. It's going to send a trade offer, offering an item, but I can't figure out how to click on the item. I tried using Resurrectio but it won't work. I think it's because you have to double click on the item.

TL;DR How to double click with CasperJS?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`doubleclick()` function from the mouse module](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/mouse.html#doubleclick) to double click on an element either based on position or selector:

```
casper.waitForSelector(buttonSelector, function(){
    this.mouse.doubleclick(buttonSelector);
});
```

This will create a native doubleclick event which shouldn't be distinguishable from a doubleclick in a normal browser. This uses PhantomJS' [`page.sendEvent()`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/send-event.html) function